# Viewing a character's catcode, and listing all characters with a given catcode

Tags: catcodes

1. How can I view the catcode of a character given by its ASCII number?
2. Is there a way to list all the characters (represented by their ASCII numbers) that are associated with a given catcode? For instance, how to list all the end-of-line characters, i.e. all the characters with catcode 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You can use `\showthe\catcode32`  and TeX will stop at that point and show you the category code of a space (10). You can also use `\the\catcode32`  which expands to the category code. Note that in both cases, I included a space after the number. The space causes TeX to stop reading the number.
2. You could iterate through all 256 characters and output the ones that match the category code you want.

Here's some code that will typeset all of the current category codes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\charcount
\begin{document}
\charcount=0
\loop\ifnum\charcount<256
    Character \number\charcount \space has category code
    \number\catcode\charcount .\endgraf
    \advance\charcount by 1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure: TeX only accepts ASCII characters, correct? So the methods you described won't work with numbers greater than 255, right?

Comment: @EvanAad TeX90 is 8-bit: this is also true for pdfTeX (which is the common engine is use today). If you are using LuaTeX or XeTeX then the full Unicode range is available. (u)pTeX (for CJK use) is a bit of an oddity ...

Comment: That's true of TeX, eTeX, and pdfTeX. I'm really not sure what XeTeX or LuaTeX do. I've almost never used them.

Comment: @JosephWright: Do LuaTeX and XeTeX have the concept of Catcode? If so, does every unicode character have a catcode?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes (to both questions).

Comment: @EvanAad Of course: they are TeX derivatives, and in XeTeX's case back-compatible other than where Unicode compatibility requires a change. LuaTeX isn't back-compatible but is still 'TeX like', certainly to the point of being able to set `\catcode`. See `load-unicode-data.tex` for how catcodes are set for both XeTeX and LuaTeX for the entire Unicode range, starting from the source Unicode data files.

Comment: @JosephWright: So what are the answers to both questions I posed in my original post in the context of LuaTeX, resp. XeTeX?

Comment: @EvanAad Unchanged bar the need for a rather longer loop for part (2) ...

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer, but if you're looking for just end of line characters, for example, then you can add `\ifnum\catcode\charcount=5` at the start of the loop and `\fi` before the `\advance` line.

Answer (score 8):

An additional note on the XeTeX/LuaTeX side of things: unlike in the TeX/pdfTeX engines where a "character" can have a value from 0 to 255 (inclusive), in both XeTeX and LuaTeX a character can have a value from 0 to 1114111 (inclusive). This latter number (`10FFFF` in hexadecimal) is the number of code points in Unicode (although only about a tenth of them have actually been [assigned meanings](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/HowMany.html) so far).

If you'd like to list only all characters with category code 5 (say), you can do that with a loop as suggested by TH.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcount\charcount
\charcount=0
\loop\ifnum\charcount<1114112 % Change to 256 if not using XeTeX/LuaTeX
  \ifnum\catcode\charcount=5
    Character \number\charcount \ has category code \number\catcode\charcount .

  \fi
  \advance\charcount by 1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

(By default the only end-of-line character is ASCII 13 (aka [U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)](https://codepoints.net/U+000D) in Unicode), even in XeTeX/LuaTeX.)

With LuaTeX, one additionally has the option of doing all this looping and checking in Lua code instead of TeX macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
  for i = 0, 1114111 do
    if tex.getcatcode(i) == 5 then
      tex.print("Character " .. i .. " has category code " .. tex.getcatcode(i) .. ".")
    end
  end
}
\end{document}
```