# Print category codes of all 256 possible input bytes?

Tags: catcodes

The title.

Is there a way to print (to the log file) the category code of every single possible input byte, either in order, or in some tabular form?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [Generating a catcode table in Latex (with \typeout to terminal)?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/60951) I think.

Comment: @AlanMunn It is (voted), although the answer there makes it look a lot more complicated than it need be.

Comment: It's also a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375940/viewing-a-characters-catcode-and-listing-all-characters-with-a-given-catcode which IMO has simpler answers.